# Woocommerce header on basket page not removing, only on checkout page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

There's a header on my Woocommerce basket page I can't remove. I've tried

```
.woocommerce .page-header { display : none; }
```

This got it away on the checkout page, but not the basket page, so I tried this using the page id, with no luck

```
.woocommerce .page-id-905 #header_meta { display: none; }
```

Comment: Can you share the html to see the structure of your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your website, the class header is `tb-page-header` so you can try:

`.woocommerce-cart .tb-page-header { display: none; }`

Comment: See my code, I have edited it regarding to your class name